# Can I connect a generic bluetooth headphone to Xbox One?

Tags: xbox-one

I have Bluetooth Auvio headphones, which I bought on radioshack and I would like to know if there is any way to connect them to my Xbox One, so I can hear sound and use the mic.

Comment: What kind of bluetooth headphones?  Please provide more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't use a bluetooth headset with the Xbox One. According to [Connecting Compatible Headsets](https://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-one/accessories/connect-compatible-headset):

- Headsets can only be connected to the Xbox One Wireless Controller. They can’t be connected to third-party wired controllers.
- The Xbox One console does not feature Bluetooth functionality. Headsets cannot connect to the console using Bluetooth.

Answer (score 3):

YOU CAN! if you have a pc/laptop, running windows you can connect any kind of headphones.  I have the Arcits 7 wireless headphones and they are not wireless with xbox one because xbox one does not have usb audio capabilities. so I messed around and came up with a way!

1. download (xbox app beta) from the store
2. open both (xbox app beta) and (xbox app)
3. make sure your xbox one is on
4. on the beta, go down to (connect)
5. connect your xbox one to your xbox beta app
6. click (stream) at the top, once connected
7. minimize xbox beta app once you see your xbox screen show up in real time
8. go into the (xbox app)
9. click on (partys)
10. create a party
11. plug in whatever headphones you want, either aux cord or usb
12. open your computers (settings)
13. type in the search bar "audio"
14. choose "manage audio devices"
15. connect your headphones
16. go back to xbox app
17. in the party you created click "party options"
18. then click "change audio devices"
19. choose your headphones
20. mess around with steps 19 & 15 to get them connected if they aren't already

now you should be able to hear game audio from the xbox beta app stream, and the party chat from the xbox app, have fun!

Comment: Nice. Now I have a a wired phone, but I'll definitely try that out!

Answer (score 2):

While there isn't a native way to do this there are plenty of ways to bridge between your Xbox One and bluetooth headphones. Here is a good article explaining how you can do this with a [$20 add on](http://www.howtogeek.com/219326/how-to-add-bluetooth-headphones-to-your-hdtv/)

> The next thing you’ll need is a Bluetooth transmitter. This device hooks up to one of the audio outputs on your TV or receiver, and then pairs with whatever Bluetooth headphones you decide on.

Note that this would not let you use the mic.

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged because the link could die in the future. You should include relevant info from the link in your answer.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: I like this answer because this is basically how I have another set of headphones set up -- with a "dongle" that takes sound out of the TV -- and that works pretty well.